# Animating a button to look like a spinner on click

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

So basically I have a button. When it is clicked the first time I want it to display a spinner animation (kind of like the game twister, the spinner thing). I want this animation on the button itself. Preferably as the background. I have the other part of the button working correctly where when it is pressed again it stops pointing in a direction at random. Any ideas on how to get this working?

```
-(IBAction)spinnerButton:(id)sender{
NSString *display;
if (pressCount%2 == 0) {
    NSString *spinning;
    spinning = @"Press again to stop spinner.";
    display = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",spinning];

    sender.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray: imageArray];
    sender.animationDuration = 1.0;
    sender.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    sender.startAnimating;
}
```

The imageArray is put together here.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:8];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"piece%d.png", i]]];
}
}
```

My thought is that it needs to look something like this

```
[sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"piece1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but I'm not exactly sure how to place the array in it and make set the duration and all that stuffs. Thanks any help is welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: anyone looking for Swift UI  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77146484/5264832

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work fine. I placed an Image View over the top of the button. It still allowed me to click the button and it allowed me to tie the images and animation in correctly.