# How to add Spinner Indicator on Programmatically created Button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiactivityindicatorview

hello I have created button dynamically on my Static TableView like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height))

  let button   = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 414, 65)

        button.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:buttonAction, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState:UIControlState.Normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Variables.MONTESERRAT_REGULAR, size: 20.0)
  button.backgroundColor = UIColor().blueColor()       //top
         footerView.addSubview(button!)


        return footerView
}
```

I want to show spinner on top of button when Its clicked. I know how to make the click function or how to create a spinner. I just don't know how to place the spinner on top of button in place of title so that when user clicks the button, title hides and spinner moves on title place. I hope you understand what I am saying

Comment: add the spinner as subview of the button. set center of spinner as button.center and:
[button addSubview:yourspinner];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *myspinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [myspinner setCenter:button.center];
    [button addSubview:myspinner];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my swift version

```
let loginSpinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let loginSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
    loginSpinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loginSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
    return loginSpinner
}()
```

Then in my `viewDidLoad` function:

```
    loginButton.addSubview(loginSpinner)
    loginSpinner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginButton.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    loginSpinner.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loginButton.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

And finally calling the `loginSpinner.startAnimating()` and `loginSpinner.stopAnimating()` functions where needed.

Note: When starting and stoping animating I also disable the button and so unset the title for the disabled button so the spinner replaces the title `loginButton.setTitle("", for: .disabled) // clear the title when it is disabled to just show the spinner`

Answer (score 1):

1. You create a spinner (`UIActivityIndicatorView`), also make it to autohide (`setHidesWhenStopped:`)
2. You add it as subview to your button (`addSubview`)
3. You put it in the center of your button (`setCenter:`)
4. On button is pressed you setTitle to empty string (`setTitle:forControlState:`) and run the spinner (`startAnimating`)

Answer (score 1):

**If someone looking for Swift UI code [SWIFT 5]**

[image: Button Animation with circular indicator]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonContentView: View {
    @State private var isButtonPressed = false
    @State private var isLoading = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    isButtonPressed.toggle()
                    isLoading.toggle()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    withAnimation {
                        isButtonPressed.toggle()
                        isLoading.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }) {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                    Text(isButtonPressed ? "" : "Press Me")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: isButtonPressed ? 60 : 200, height: isButtonPressed ? 60 : 50)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .clipShape(isButtonPressed ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50) : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                }
                
            }
            
            if isLoading {
                CircularProgressView()
                    .opacity(isButtonPressed ? 1 : 0)
                    .scaleEffect(isButtonPressed ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CircularProgressView: View {
    @State private var rotation = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .trim(from: 0.08, to: 1.0)
            .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 4, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(rotation))
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        
            .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
                            rotation = 360.0
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}

struct ButtonContentView_previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ButtonContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/building-an-async-swiftui-button/

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I normally do it, and there's a few differing behaviors which you can utilize:

```
let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)

spinner.frame = CGRect(x: -20.0, y: 6.0, width: 20.0, height: 20.0) // (or wherever you want it in the button)
spinner.startAnimating()
spinner.alpha = 0.0

button.addSubview(spinner)
```

You can change the alpha accordingly. Or use hidden properties, stop/start animating, etc.